# How you call the restart service

Tags: cron

how can I execute this command with crontab

0 * * * * service ogp_agent restart

It doesn't work for me, what should I do?

Comment: Normally a cron daemon would read the crontab entries and execute the commands. What operating system are you using and is the cron daemon enabled?

Comment: Debian 7
if it is enabled